# How to call a list of list in prolog

Tags: prolog

How to call a list of list in Prolog for exemple I have this list :

```
list([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]).
```

I want to call my list in the element_at function :

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1).
element_at(X,[_|L],K) :-
   element_at(X,L,K1),
   K is K1 + 1.
```

When i call

```
element_at(X,list,2)
```

I don't have a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We retrieve a value from our knowledge base by a call to a predicate,

```
list(L)
```

so the whole query at the prompt is

```
list(L), element_at(X, L, 2).
```

Or define it in a source file,

```
my_query(X) :- list(L), element_at(X, L, 2).
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have a result.

Well, you **do** have a result: failure. But you expected success.  Here is a  very general method how you can locate such errors in Prolog yourself:

> If you encounter **unexpected failure**, simply generalize your program.

In your particular case, `element_at(X,list,2)` fails. Maybe it should be `3` in place of `2`? Or maybe another number? There is an easy way of guessing in Prolog: Simply replace `3` by a variable! By the same token, you can remove goals in your definition. I will use `*` to mark those.

Here is a generalization of your program that still fails — and thus there must be an error in the remaining part:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*(_).

?- element_at(X, list, _/*2*/).

element_at(X,[_/*X*/|_],_/*1*/).
element_at(X,[_|L],K) :-
   * element_at(X,L,K1),
   * K is K1 + 1.
```